# How to type UTF-8 Emojis with the pynput.keyboard module

Tags: python, utf-8, keyboard, emoji, pynput

I'm trying to type UTF-8 Emojis with the Keyboard but I always get the following exception.
Pynput seeems to correctly convert the UTF-8 Symbol but can't type it out.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pasteEmoji.py", line 11, in <module>
    keyboard.type('\U0001f61a')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pynput/keyboard/_base.py", line 468, in type
    raise self.InvalidCharacterException(i, character)
pynput.keyboard._base.InvalidCharacterException: (0, '')
```

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import time

keyboard = Controller()

print("2 Seconds left...")
time.sleep(2)

keyboard.type('\U0001f61a')
```

Does someone has any ideas how to typeout UTF-8 Symbols?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Apparently, `pynput` thinks that  is an untypable character (at least on your platform). Maybe this library isn't the right tool to create keyboard shortcuts for typing emojis...

Answer (score 0):

Not quite the solution you're looking for, and perhaps only a partial one. But I found that xdotool will send those characters. Firefox(and potentially other browsers) seems like it disables the ability however.

You can implement it like this:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["xdotool", "type", "\U0001F61A"])
```

There's also a python library that implements xdotool called [libxdo](https://github.com/rshk/python-libxdo). But it hasn't been updated in years and I didn't test it yet.

I'll update this if I find a better solution.

EDIT: I found a very hacky solution that works, seems to be pretty fast, and works in Firefox. It requires the CTRL+SHIFT+U unicode HEX shortcut to be enabled. Can test by pressing those buttons and if the u is underlined, you're good.

```
from evdev import UInput, ecodes as e

ui = UInput()

string = "1F61A" #The unicode hexcode. Make sure it's in uppercase
ui.write(e.EV_KEY, e.KEY_LEFTCTRL, 1)       
ui.write(e.EV_KEY, e.KEY_LEFTSHIFT, 1)      
ui.write(e.EV_KEY, e.KEY_U, 1)      
ui.write(e.EV_KEY, e.KEY_U, 0)
ui.write(e.EV_KEY, e.KEY_LEFTSHIFT, 0)  
ui.write(e.EV_KEY, e.KEY_LEFTCTRL, 0)
for s in string:
    exec("ui.write(e.EV_KEY, e.KEY_{}, 1)".format(s))
    exec("ui.write(e.EV_KEY, e.KEY_{}, 0)".format(s))
ui.write(e.EV_KEY, e.KEY_ENTER, 1)  
ui.write(e.EV_KEY, e.KEY_ENTER, 0)  
ui.syn()
```

Not pretty, but it's working well for me.

EDIT2: Last edit. I resurrected an old issue for this on pynput's github [here](https://github.com/moses-palmer/pynput/issues/94). And a fix was created that worked for me, and should be pushed to the master branch soon!